# Как изменить переменную в классе

Tags: php

Как передать из метода actionIndex передать переменную в конструктор AdminBase? Переменная нужна для того чтобы передать в User::checkLogged()

```
abstract class AdminBase{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //$this->checkAdmin();
    }

    public static function checkAdmin(){
        $userId = User::checkLogged();
        $user = User::getUserById($userId);
        if($user['role'] == 'admin')
            return true;
        die('Access denied');
    }
}
```

Наследник:

```
class AdminController extends AdminBase
{
    public $locale;
    public function actionIndex($locale='')
    {
        $title = 'Админ Панель';
        require_once (ROOT . '/views/admin/index.php');
        return true;
    }

}
```

Comment: может вы имели в виду `функцию класса`, а не `класс`?

Comment: А где у вас, собственно, создание инстанса AdminBase?

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Если переменная стала доступна только внутри метода класса, то конструктор этого класса уже отработал и ничего в него передать не выйдет. Только во вновь создаваемый экземпляр класса.

Если переменная нужна в конструкторе чтоб потом быть использованной в других методах, то заведите свойство в классе, задайте ему значение из метода, и используйте где требуется вообще не трогая конструктор:

```
class foo {
  $bar;
  function f1() { $this->bar = 1; }
  function f2() { echo $this->bar; }
}
```

Рано или поздно узнаете про `DI` и решите внедрить значение свойства из вне. Можете сразу подготовиться и добавить аксессоры для свойства:

```
class foo {
  $bar;
  function f1() { $this->setBar(1); }
  function f2() { echo $this->getBar(); }
  function setBar($bar) { $this->bar = $bar; }
  function getBar() { return $this->bar; }
}
```